# Are transitions strips necessary from room to room if installing luxury vinyl planks throughout house?

Tags: installation, vinyl-flooring, vinyl, transition

I would like to replace our carpet and tile with the locking/floating luxury vinyl planks throughout most of the house. Our house runs long and think it would look so much nicer without transition strips from room to room where there will be lvp only, such as between the living room and kitchen/family room as shown in this photo taken from the entry way. Is this possible or do you recommend transition strips to avoid buckling, etc.?

[image]

Comment: You need to read the instructions for your product. Some have maximum room lengths, beyond which an expansion channel must be installed.

Comment: Can you add the identity of the planks you plan to use?  Also, dimensions and layout of the area and the direction you plan to run the planks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! We like a Coretec product because of the color. The planks are 5"x4ft and we'd like to run the planks parallel to the length of the house (the right wall).

Answer (score 1):

Transitions strips are generally to provide a transition from one flooring surface to another; oftentimes because of a height difference. Sometimes they provide a threshold from one room to another where the flooring is the same but a limit barrier is desired, like from the living room to the kitchen/dining room.

Transitions give visual cues and can change the design dynamics visually to a space—make it look bigger or more cozy, etc.

If you’re using a single kind of flooring throughout and there are no height differences or underlayment/stability issues, you don’t have to install transitions.

You do need to install base of some kind where the flooring meets the walls. Doorways, around corners and curved spaces require base and sometimes transitions, depending on the flooring and installation layout.

Be sure to do a “dry” layout and determine where you need to make cuts, keeping in mind, the cuts should be made at the least visible part of the floor. For example, in a small bathroom, you generally want to use a full tile coming out from the wall or tub and make cuts at the threshold of the door.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! By "base", do you mean quarter-round or shoe molding? If so, I'm hoping the baseboards will cover up the gap between flooring and walls and try to minimize quarter-round or shoe as much as possible.

Comment: Quarter round is usual but you can be creative with your choice. Check youtube for alternative ideas on base/baseboards.  Depending on the thickness or depth of the baseboard you’re using, it may cover to the edge of the flooring (be certain to remove existing base for best results). Follow manufacturer’s installation instructions.